# How to refactor a React hook so that I can call it inside a callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on some sign in code, and want to add the functionality to check whether the user is an admin or not. I know that I can't call a hook within a callback, and I've checked other answers on SO, but still can't wrap my head around how to use the hook's functionality. **The problem is it has to be triggered from within a form's submit function - so I can't call it at the top level of my React component, as the error message suggests.** (`React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`)

**Can anyone help me figure out how to refactor this code to get the hook's functionality into a callback?**

***Description of code:***

SignIn component - is a form with an `onSubmit` function, which calls a custom `signIn` function.

`signIn` function - takes user/pass and a callback function to be called only if the Auth flow succeeds.

hook `useCheckUserAdmin` - check if user is an admin. Ideally called inside `signIn`'s callback.

`onSuccess` function - redirects to either admin or client homepage. called inside `signIn`'s callback, right after the hook.

***Actual Code:***

Here's the main Login component (note some irrelevant pieces are removed), including `onSuccess` function

```js
const SignInComponent = () => {
const onSuccess = React.useCallback(
    (userIsAdmin) => {
      // history.replace(etc. etc.) <- some boolean logic to direct to an admin or a regular user page
    },
    []
  );
return <Formik
 onSubmit={async (values) => {
  await signIn(values.username, values.password, (userId) => {
    const userIsAdmin = useCheckUserAdmin(userId)
    onSuccess(userIsAdmin);
    setError(null);
  }).catch((err) => {
    setError(err.message);
  });
}}
>
}
```

The custom hook `useCheckUserAdmin` (simplified for readability):

```js
import { useGetUser } from "../api/composedHooks";

export default function useCheckUserAdmin(userId: string) {
  const userQuery = useGetUser({
    variables: { id: userId },
  });
  return userQuery.userType;
}
```

The signIn function:

```js
async function signIn(
  username: string,
  password: string,
  callback: (userId: string) => void
) {
  try {
    const result = await Auth.signIn({
      username,
      password,
    });
    if (result) {
      return callback(result.username);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("error signing in:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's really no way to call the custom hook in your callback (since it fails the rules of hooks check). If you must perform this logic inside of a custom hook (which may not be necessary since i cant see why that requires stateful logic), one option would be to return the necessary function from the custom hook:

```
SignInComponent = () => {
   const checkUserIsAdmin = useCheckUserIsAdmin() // non-conditionally call the hook
}
```

Then in your callback something like:

```
callback(checkUserIsAdmin)
```

And your custom hook you call any needed hooks & return the function:

```
// Call any needed hooks (useLocation..useHistory..etc)
const checkUserIsAdmin = () => {...logic operating on userId}
return checkUserIsAdmin
```

Not sure if it helps but it's one way to satisfy the conditions of your problem.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the purpose of using `userId` as state inside my hook? Could I just return `checkUserIsAdmin` function without returning setUserId, and then in my callback do `callback(checkUserIsAdmin(userId))`?

Comment: I didn't fully understand the use case but absolutely. The only reason to save it in state would be if you want to later call other functions based on that id, within this component.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting idea. So the last code box, where you define `checkUserIsAdmin`, that would be in the hook definition? So I can pass the function out and use it elsewhere without using the hook, right?

Comment: Yes that's the idea, you call the hook once to initialize it and pass the function around as needed. I'm assuming that there must be some other hook called within your custom hook (since you received the error you did) so the solution is to allow those hooks to run unconditionally while returning a function which operates on their outputs.

Comment: Hmm. Just sat down to try this today, and realized that I can't allow the hook to run unconditionally, because it needs to take a userId argument. And I won't have a userId until AFTER the SignIn component loads once and the user inputs their info, clicks login, and we validate their credentials. How would I specify that checkUserIsAdmin takes an argument, but only if it exists?

Comment: Assuming that the argument is the user id you can just pass that directly. If it doesn't exist maybe do not call the function at all and raise an error/alert? It's not an expected result so you don't need to check if the user is admin. Or am i misunderstanding something?